# How to send same video resolution every time in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

How to send video resolution 640x480 every time and in every device in webrtc ?
i'm using following code

```
      video: {
        width: {
          exact: 640
        },
        height: {
          exact: 480
        }
      },
```

but its not working always.
In forums as i understand CPU optimizes and shrinks resolution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably control the resolution of the video being sent.

The structure you have shown, when passed to `getUserMedia`, controls the size of the video captured by the user's webcam.  This video is later passed to WebRTC, which compresses it and adapts it to the available network throughput.  If the network is slow, WebRTC will do one or more of the following:

- reduce the video quality; or
- reduce the video framerate; or
- reduce the video resolution.

While you cannot constrain the resolution of the video, you can influence the choice made by the video encoder by setting the track's `contentHint` to the string `detail`.  This works fairly reliably in most cases, but the video encoder may still choose to reduce the resolution if the available throughput falls too low.

Comment: That is, I can not influence the video resolution constant in any way if network throughput drops? 
in my case it is acceptable to reduce the framerate to preserve the resolution of the video stream contentHint = detail will be the right solution?

Comment: It wil work in most cases.  There are no guarantees, though, and the resolution might still drop in extreme cases, so you should be prepared to handle that case.

Comment: Thank you, I tested and everything works. After restoring the speed of the Internet, the frames will return to normal?

Comment: They should do.